# How can I remove "\n" not followed by another "\n" in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to remove "\n" which is not followed by another "\n".

I have a sample text here. What I want to do is that when I press a button, I want to remove "\n" not followed by another "\n" from the text below which is in textarea HTML tag.

```
abcdefg

hijklmn
opqrstu
vwxyz

12345
67890
abcde

zzzzz
```

So, the result I expect is something like this. It only removes "\n"s not followed by another "\n".

```
abcdefg

hijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

1234567890abcde

zzzzz
```

But the result I actually get is this.

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890abcde

zzzzz
```

This is the javascript code and HTML code I have now.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="remove-line-breaks.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>remove-line-breaks</h1>

<h2>Before</h2>
<textarea id="original-textarea" cols="30" rows="15">
abcdefg

hijklmn
opqrstu
vwxyz

12345
67890
abcde

zzzzz
</textarea>
<br />
<input id ="modify-text-btn" type="submit" value="change" />


<h2>after</h2>
<textarea id="modified-textarea" cols="30" rows="15"></textarea>

</body>
</html>
```

**Javascript**

```
window.onload = function(){

var modifyTextBtn = document.getElementById("modify-text-btn");
modifyTextBtn.addEventListener("click", modifyText, false);

var originalTextarea = document.getElementById("original-textarea");
var modifiedTextarea = document.getElementById("modified-textarea");

function modifyText(){

    var pattern = new RegExp("[^\\n](\\n)[^\\n]");
    var newStr = originalTextarea.value;

    while (pattern.test(newStr)) {
        newStr = newStr.replace(pattern.exec(newStr)[1], "");
    }

    modifiedTextarea.value = newStr;

}




}
```

Could anyone please help me to solve this problem?

Comment: You desired output does not match you description, when you have a pair of `\n` the second one should be stripped as well since it is not followed by a `\n`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More or less, you're doing a lot more processing than you need to.  Change your `modifyText` function to this:

```
function modifyText(){
    var pattern = new RegExp("([^\\n])\\n([^\\n])", "g");
    modifiedTextarea.value = originalTextarea.value.replace(pattern, "$1$2");
}
```

The first change is in the definition of `pattern` . . . you' notice at the end, I added `, "g"` in the `new RegExp` constructor.  That makes the pattern global, meaning that, when it's applied, it will affect all instances of the pattern

Once that is set up, all you have to do is call the replace once against the field value and assign it to the target field value.

---

**UPDATE:** Sorry for chopping off those characters.   :D  I've updated both the regex and the replacement pattern.

The regex now only actually captures the characters **around** the line break and then, in the replacement, puts them back in, without the line break in between them.

Comment: Thanks! I tried your code right now. But, it removed some strings besides "\n".

result I got is this.

"abcdefg

hijklmpqrstwxyz

1234789bcde

zzzzz
"

Comment: Oh right . . . my bad . . . it will clear out the two "non-linebreak" characters around the line break.  Let me fix that.

Comment: if you want to catch double new lines at the begining of the string, you should replace `([^\\n])` with `([^\\n]|^)`. However +1

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte - Yep . . . and, you could do similar with `$` to catch double lines at the end.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
var r = s.replace(/\n\n/g, '\n\n\n').replace(/\n(?!\n)/g, '');
"abcdefg

hijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

1234567890abcde

zzzzz"
```

Answer (score 0):

To retain double newlines you can replace any newline that is preceded and followed by anything except a newline-

```
modifiedTextarea.value= originalTextarea.value.replace(/(.+)\n(.+)/g,'$1$2');
```